# Is it possible to have 2 Dialog themes

Tags: jquery, dialog, themes

Just a general question. jQuery dialog according to the API, Dosen';t allow for a theme to be included in it's parameters. So I am guessing that each theme must be declared like thus.

```
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

How can I use the second theme in a modal dialog as I cannot see a way to call the theme from dialog. I have included sample code below. So my question is, how do I call a specific theme for use in my code. Thanks

```
$("#box_frtv").bind("chosen:maxselected",
            function() {
                //alert('Only 1 box can be selected. Thank you.');
                            $("html").append("<div id='dialog-bferror' />");
                            var $dialogBFError = $("#dialog-bferror");
                            $dialogBFError.html('<br />Only 1 box can be selected . Thank you.');
                            $dialogBFError.dialog({
                                autoOpen: true,
                                modal: true,
                                title: 'File Error',
                                position: ['center', 'center'],
                                width: 400,
                                height: 200,
                                draggable: true,
                                resizable: false,
                                buttons: {
                                    Close: function() {
                                        $(this).dialog("close");
                                    }
                                }
                            });
        });
```

Comment: Just edit the second css in order to use the styles and classes for the dialog or rename the classes..

Comment: Robert Could you expand on your answer please. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the two CSS files using a "diff" tool. Then make a local CSS file that contains the sections that are different in one of the files, and add the ID of the dialog that should use those styles to all those sections. For instance, if this line is different in the second CSS files:

```
.ui-button .ui-button-text { display: block; line-height: 1.4;  }
```

put this in your new CSS file:

```
#box_frtv .ui-button .ui-button-text { display: block; line-height: 1.4;  }
```

Then load this local CSS file in place of the second theme from the net.

Comment: This is what i'm talking about...+1

Comment: BTW What is a 'diff tool'?

Comment: For example, the `diff` command on Unix. I think most IDEs also have a command to show the difference between files.

Comment: New one on me. Shall have to look into that. Thanks